# Is it true that $[0,\omega_1]$ is scattered?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that $[0,\omega_1]$ is [scattered](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aScattered_Space)?

I think that it is, since any non-empty (nonsingeltone) closed sets, either contains a successor ordinal, or contains at list two limit ordinals whic are isolated with respect to one another.

Is my intuition correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** If $A\subseteq[0,\omega_1]$ is non-empty, $\min A$ is isolated in $A$.